# ¿Por qué aparece la palabra "lo" en esta frase? "Ella me recomendó centrarmé más en *lo* bien ... que en *lo* tarde que..."

Tags: gramática, artículos

He estado leyendo unos artículos en español para mejorar, y una frase en este [artículo](https://www.nytimes.com/es/2019/03/04/adiccion-al-celular/?action=click&contentCollection=reposado&region=rank&module=package&version=highlights&contentPlacement=1&pgtype=collection) me ha confundido mucho:

> Ella me recomendó concentrarme más en **lo** bien que me sentía por ver menos la pantalla que en **lo** tarde que quizá haya llegado a eventos como el divorcio de Jeff Bezos.

No entiendo por qué hay tantos "lo" en esa frase ni a qué se refieren. Y más importante, ¿qué significa la parte "en lo tarde que quizá haya llegado a eventos"?

¿Significa *"in that the events might arrive late"*? ¿Y por qué no dice "en que quizá los eventos hayan llegado tarde"?

Comment: He editado el texto para hacerlo más idiomático y he corregido las faltas de ortografía, sobre todo la concordancia de género entre el determinante y el sustantivo: esta frase, una frase. Échale un ojo a las diferencias entre tu texto y el texto modificado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Lo" en estas frases funciona como artículo. 
Para entender por qué aparece imagínate la frase con dos sustantivos:

- Ella me recomendó concentrarme más en *mis estudios* que en *el trabajo*.

El trabajo es masculino, por eso tiene el artículo "el". Estudios es masculino plural por eso tiene el artículo pronominal "mis" (en femenino sería igual).

Si ahora sustituyes el complemento por una oración subordinada, ya no puedes ponerle un artículo masculino o femenino, porque la oración subordinada no tiene género. Por eso se utiliza el artículo neutro "lo":

- Me gusta la playa  =>  Me gusta lo que dices
- Pienso en la playa => Pienso en lo que dices

En tu ejemplo hay otra "indirección" más. Porque la oración subordinada se aplica a un adjetivo:

- Me gusta lo que dices => Me gusta lo bien que lo dices
- Me concentro en la música => Me concentro en lo buena que es la música

En cuanto a la segunda parte de tu pregunta, hay una sutil diferencia entre "en que quizá los eventos hayan llegado tarde" y "lo tarde que quizá hayan llegado los eventos". En el primer ejemplo se concentra en si los eventos han llegado tarde o no. En el segundo ejemplo en cuan tarde han llegado. El primero es algo binario y el segundo es una gradación.

Answer (score 5):

No estaba seguro de cuál era la función de esos "lo"s que indicas, así que he investigado un poco.

Una vez encontrado [este análisis sintáctico](http://emiliomontehernanz.blogspot.com/2011/01/analisis-sintactico-completo-de-las.html) de una frase parecida, he recurrido al D.R.A.E para reafirmar lo expuesto en ese blog.

En tu frase ambos "lo"s están actuando como **determinantes neutros**.

Según el D.R.A.E

[el, la, lo [m,f,n]](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ESraxkH)

> 9. art. deter. **n**. Ante adjetivos en masculino singular, complementos prepositivos con la preposición de u oraciones de
>      relativo, forma sintagmas nominales definidos que denotan entidades a
>      las que se atribuyen las propiedades descritas por tales
>      modificadores. 
>    *Le encanta lo étnico.
>     No me explicaste lo de ayer.
>     ¿No
>      te interesa lo que dice?*

La n que he resaltado es de **neutro** que es lo que identifica a **lo** dentro del grupo de determinantes: el (masculino), la (femenino) y lo (neutro).

Ahí arriba está la explicación formal, pero a mí me queda más claro la que aparece en el blog que he mencionado antes:

> *No te imaginas **lo bien** que lo pasé y **lo poco** que me costó alcanzar el
>   premio.*
>
> Oración compuesta por coordinación copulativa (“y”) y subordinación
>   (dos adjetivas y una sustantiva). La conjunción “y” une dos SN en
>   función de CD, **cuyos núcleos son adverbios sustantivados, “bien” y
>   “poco”, a través del determinante neutro “lo”**; estos “sustantivos” son
>   los antecedentes de las dos Prop. Sub. Adjs. en función de CN: “que lo
>   pase” (“que” =CCM) y “que…premio” (“que=CCCantidad). Dentro de esta
>   última proposición, hallamos una Prop. Sub. Sust. de Infinitivo (no
>   flexionada) que es “alcanzar el premio”, que es el Sujeto de la
>   Adjetiva.

Resumiendo y simplificando, **lo** se ha usado para **sustantivar** los adverbios bien y tarde en tu frase. Creo que @julodnik lo ha expuesto mejor y de forma más legible pero quería añadir la referencia del D.R.A.E

---

Por otra parte

> en lo tarde que quizá haya llegado a eventos

creo que puede traducirse [Thanks for the help, mdewey!]

> how late I might have arrived at events

El sujeto es yo [I], y no los eventos, como ocurre en tus propuestas. Yo soy el que llega tarde a los eventos. En ambos idiomas se trata de una metáfora, no está hablando de llegar [arrive] físicamente al divorcio de Jeff Bezos, sino de enterarse [be aware] de la noticia tarde.

Comment: I think "how late I might have arrived at events" might be more idiomatic but it does not alter the value of your answer of course.

Comment: @mdewey I was not sure, I like your version best. Thanks! Editing ...

Answer (score 4):

Esta respuesta viene a complementar las anteriores (hubiera querido hacer un comentario, pero habría sido demasiado extenso).

No estoy de acuerdo con el comienzo de la definición de "lo" que cita RubioRic, cuando dice:

> Ante adjetivos en masculino singular...

En realidad, si bien "lo" tiene mucho de determinante neutro, también tiene algo de adverbio de cantidad (espero no ser excomulgado por esto). El punto es que, salvo en el caso de las relativas o cuando realmente sustantiva el adjetivo o adverbio que sigue, en muchos casos ese "lo" funciona como cuantificador y puede ser reemplazado por "cuán", en cuyo caso puede utilizarse con adjetivos en femenino y en plural:

- No podía creer **lo linda** que estaba.
- Es inaudito **lo difíciles** que se han vuelto estas preguntas.

Ahora bien, debo admitir que si reemplazamos "lo" por "cuán", debemos eliminar el relativo "que":

- No podía creer **cuán linda** estaba.
- Es inaudito **cuán difíciles** se han vuelto estas preguntas.

En la página 356 de "El arte de escribir bien en español - Manual de corrección de estilo", de María Marta García Negroni (coord.) y Laura Pérgola - Mirta Stern, encontramos esta referencia que contradice la entrada 9 que DRAE asigna a "lo":

> *11.7.2.1.2. El artículo neutro*
>
> El artículo neutro "lo" se une a adjetivos de cualquier género y número y sirve para sustantivarlos. Su valor es a menudo enfático o ponderativo. Ejemplos:
>
> *¡Tendrías que haber visto lo linda que iba!*
>
> *¡Tendrías que haber visto lo lindas que iban!*

A continuación, pego todo el artículo sobre este tema, que creo puede ser de interés:

> [image: García Negroni]

A partir del comentario de RubioRic, es verdad que "lo" no siempre se traducirá como el adverbio interrogativo o exclamativo "how" (o "what", delante de adjetivo y sustantivo), sino que a veces -- cuando la sustantivación sea más abstracta como dice Negroni en su segundo grupo de ejemplos -- la traducción será la frase nominal equivalente en inglés, con artículo o sin él (lo barato = cheap things / lo cortés = politeness). No obstante, en los ejemplos de OP se usa "how" puesto que se hace referencia al **grado** de bienestar o al **nivel** de tardanza:

- Ella me recomendó concentrarme más en lo bien que me sentía por ver menos la pantalla que en lo tarde que quizá haya llegado a eventos como el divorcio de Jeff Bezos.
- She recommended that I focus more on **how** well I felt by reducing the time I looked at my phone screen than on **how** late I might have learnt about events such as Jeff Bezos's divorce.

Comment: +1 Buen apunte con el aspecto cuantitativo de "lo", que sin saber he relacionado al incluir "how" en mi traducción. Aunque creo que no se aplica del todo en la frase original.

Comment: @RubioRic Sin embargo, creo que "how" se aplica perfectamente a los ejemplos de OP. Ver mi agregado arriba.

Comment: Tienes razón. Un apunte, el artículo habla de la adicción al telefono móvil, no sería TV sino pantalla (del móvil).

Comment: Ok, I revised my translation.

Comment: El DRAE contempla el uso de *lo + [adj. m/f/sing/pl]* en la acepción 11: *art. deter. n. Pondera el grado del adjetivo o el adverbio al que modifica. U. seguido de una subordinada introducida por que. Ya sabes lo lentos que son. Admiro lo bien que trabaja.*